# Why is query time so different?

Tags: sql-server

This query returns very slowly

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM MyTable N
WHERE
    (N.[Subject] LIKE '%not_postterm%')
    OR (N.[Content] LIKE '%not_postterm%')
    OR (N.[Subject] LIKE '%not_post_term%')
    OR (N.[Content] LIKE '%not_post_term%')
```

But this returns quickly

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM MyTable N
WHERE
    (N.[Subject] LIKE '%postterm%')
    OR (N.[Content] LIKE '%postterm%')
    OR (N.[Subject] LIKE '%post_term%')
    OR (N.[Content] LIKE '%post_term%')
```

Is the reason because of the length of the string in between the wildcards?

Comment: Since you're using a leading `%` in your `LIKE` operator, both queries would normally be very slow - since no indices can be used to speed them up and they will need to do a **full table scan**: Did you run the queries in this very order? Then maybe the whole data had already been loaded by the first query, so the second is quick. Try restarting SQL Server, and run the **second** query first - is it still so fast?

Answer (score 1):

> Why is query time so different?

Both queries will perform a table scan, or a scan of an index containing the 4 WHERE-clause columns.

But both queries will stop as soon as the 100th matching row is found.  So the distribution and location of the matching rows in the table or index being scanned will control the run time of this query.

Comment: This makes sense as the items in my first query are more spread out than in the second. Thanks!